# Can't rebase and manage conflicts of Excel Sheet in the repo

Tags: git, tortoisegit

We are using TortoiseGit in my team. There is a shared excel sheet in the repo. When I commit changes and try to push, it says there is a conflict, I pulled and tried to rebase but it says it doesn't support this type of files.

Doesn't have TortoiseGit rebase support excel sheets or non text files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving a Git conflict with binary files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278081/resolving-a-git-conflict-with-binary-files)

Comment: I viewed the possible duplicate, Jubobs. I don't think it is the same. I need to rebase the file as normal text file to resolve a conflict

Comment: Since Excel files are binary files, merging changes and rebasing is pretty much mission impossible; see also https://github.com/githubtraining/zzz_deprecated-feedback/issues/45

Comment: Excel sheets are not normal text files. If it's xlsx, you could unzip them to get 'normal' text files. Still, git will see it as binary. What you could do is extract the two versions and merge the changes, using MS Excel, manually. Then commit that 'manually merged version'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get some excel merge tool, you could set external merge tool in TortoiseGit Settings:

[image]

Then, when you get conflict, you could use that tool to merge the file manually.

IIRC, there is no such tool or script. (But, word file has one.)

---

However, I got a workaround:

1. copy the diff script command from extension diff program
   [image]
2. paste to extension "merge" program, and modify the argument.
   [image]
   (wscript.exe "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\Diff-Scripts\diff-xls.js" %mine %theirs //E:javascript)
3. the log and excel context
   [image]
4. merge test branch to master
   [image]
5. get conflict, and push resolve button
   [image]
6. commit dialog is popup, and double click on excel file to invoke the script
   [image]
7. merge manually
   [image]
8. save to the local file
   [image]
9. mark the file as resolved
   [image]
10. review the merged excel file if you want, then commit

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give xltrail client a try, which is a free, open-source Git extension for Excel workbooks: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/git-xltrail (disclaimer, I'm one of the authors).

It installs a custom differ and merger for Excel workbooks to make `git diff` and `git merge` work the same way Git works for text files.

It currently works for VBA inside Excel workbooks only, but we are working on making it work for sheets, too. Essentially, when you merge, it'll work out which VBA modules have been deleted, added and modified and applies the standard three-way merge and dumps conflicted code with the standard Git notation into the affected VBA modules (which can then be manually resolved using Excel).

For an example (including a short video), have a look at: https://www.xltrail.com/blog/git-merge-excel-vba