# Git Merge - Binary File Conflict Resolution

Tags: git, binaryfiles, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

How do I resolve a binary file conflict resolution during a merge operation in git?  Here's what I've done so far:

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git merge working_branch

... [Conflicts] ...

git status
...
Unmerged paths:
        both modified:   Path/file.dll
        ...
```

I want to keep the version in the `working_branch` and discard the version in the `master`.  How do I do this?

Comment: Generally you would select one version or the other, unless there is a feasible way outside of `git` to actually create some sort of merged version (which is unlikely with DLLs, but completely possible with e.g. JAR or ZIP files...). You can select one or the other with e.g. `git checkout -- :2:Path/file.dll` or `git checkout -- :3:Path/file.dll` for the HEAD and MERGE_BRANCH versions, respectively. See `git help merge` for more details...

Comment: Oops... wrong syntax - should be `git show :2:Path/file.dll > Path/file.dll`, and similar for the slot 3 entry... Doesn't work with `git checkout`; although there is alternative syntax - `git checkout --ours -- Path/file.dll` or `git checkout --theirs -- Path/file.dll`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving a Git conflict with binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278081/resolving-a-git-conflict-with-binary-files)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out earlier today:

```
git checkout --theirs Path/file.dll
git add Path/file.dll
git commit -m "Resolved merge conflict by checking out file from working_branch and adding it to the master"
```