# ExcelCompare not working for conflicts

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-merge-conflict

I used ExcelCompare and also some python script to be able to `diff` Excel files.
When I'm making changes locally it works as expected, I can see the changes before committing.

However, when merging another branch into mine, and I have conflicts, the Excel files are seen as binaries, so I cannot check what are the differences or where the conflicts are.

Details:

We're using SourceTree

Global `.gitconfig` file contains:

```
[diff "excel"]
binary = True
textconv = python 'C:/Program Files/Git/git_diff_xlsx.py'
```

`.gitattributes` file contains:

```
*.xlsx diff=excel
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: My mistake. Looking at it again, while this question seemed similar to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278081/resolving-a-git-conflict-with-binary-files), it is not a duplicate. Removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

xltrail client (a free, open-source Git extension for Excel workbooks, I'm the author) might be helpful: https://www.xltrail.com/client.

It custom with a custom differ and merger for Excel workbooks to make `git diff` and `git merge` work the same way Git works for text files.

For an example (including a short video), have a look at: https://www.xltrail.com/blog/git-merge-excel-vba