# git branch commit does not merge into master

Tags: xcode, git, github, core-data

From git window, I executed these commands:

```
git branch 
master
*wcopy

git commit -am "modified provider features"
On branch wcopy
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/wcopy'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

git merge wcopy
Already upto date

git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

I go to git hub repository
Branch master says:
latest commit 9 days ago

Branch wcopy says:
This branch is 2 commits ahead, 5 commits behind master.
Latest commit db8bdca  18 minutes ago

I checked brnach wcopy the code is upto date
But master is behind.

I merged into master via git command, but it still shows two separate branches with master behind wcopy

(1) How can I bring master upto date?
(2) Also I renamed a file DB/Model.xcdatamodeld to Model.xcdatamodeld on my source.
But the wcopy branch shows the path as 
DB/Model.xcdatamodeld/GridModel.xcdatamodel 
says this path skips through empty directories. 
If I look at the actual code on the source, it shows the path correctly as DB/Model.xcdatamodeld
I don't know why the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
git merge wcopy
```

By doing that you merged `wcopy` into itself (which is not what you require). You should have *switched* to the `master` branch, then did the merged `wcopy` branch into `master` by doing this:

```
git pull origin wcopy
# to make sure you are up to date on wcopy branch
git checkout master
# to have your master branch up to date with the remote.
git pull origin master
git merge wcopy
# resolve possible merge conflicts if any.
git push origin master
```

This should resolve all your problems and merge branch `wcopy` with `master`.

Comment: git merge wocpy gives a bunch of errors: (1) warning: Cannot merge binary files and (2) auto-merging on some other files gives conflict(content): merge conflict. They says Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: from command tool I run git mergetool: brings up a UI with multiple windows on the xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file. I dont understand what is going on

Comment: Now I try to open the xcode project it says cannot be opened because project file cannot be parsed. I am in deep trouble now

Comment: Please read up on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278081/resolving-a-git-conflict-with-binary-files about how to resolve conflicts with binary files and look at this for how to use mergetool https://gist.github.com/karenyyng/f19ff75c60f18b4b8149

Answer (score 1):

> I merged into master via git command, but it still shows two separate branches with master behind wcopy

When you did this:

```
git merge wcopy
```

You merged `wcopy` into itself, the `wcopy` branch, which of course didn't do anything.  You should have *switched* first to the `master` branch, then did the merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge wcopy
# resolve possible merge conflicts...
git push origin master
```

Comment: Now I try to open the xcode project it says cannot be opened because project file cannot be parsed. I am in deep trouble now for reasons stated above. I go to github it says This branch is 6 commits behind master

Comment: @vrao This sounds like a possibly totally different problem.  In which case, you might want to open a new question.