# Resolve conflicts Git LFS

Tags: git, diff, rebase, conflict

When I make a `git pull --rebase`, this is what I can see when I try to resolve conflicts in a json file:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1  
Updated upstream  
oid sha256:daa8dd3be5413def66d9a12df3c011c6f1d2dbc459bdb4cbf2b5e5ed3fd7d752  
size 612325  
=======  
oid sha256:6d8dfa7c7b06fa7d7c50889d111aa50bcdf12c7535222cc007012bebdda61d17  
size 622401  
Stashed changes
```

After researches, these are lfs pointers. But I can't find any solution to resolve my conflicts.
I got the same thing when I make a git diff.
I would like to see the content of the files, not pointers

Anyone could help me?

Comment: What happens when you do `git mergetool` ? Is it a huge json ? It's not a 'standard' file to be put on LFS.

Comment: Nothing's wrong when i do git mergetool. Yes the json is quite big, it seems that's what happens with lfs when a file is big. But this is not convenient to resolve conflitcts

Comment: This is what appears after git mergetool :  
Merging:   
test/***.json  

Normal merge conflict for 'test/***.mat':  
  {local}: modified file  
  {remote}: modified file  
The merge tool bc3 is not available as 'bcompare'

Comment: instead of pull rebase/merge you could create a local branch then fetch remote dir, after this do a diff between the two conflictual versions (your local update and the remote version you just fetched) use either cli or tools like: meld, kdiff, vimmdiff etc.. this will help you figure out what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i don't think it will change anything. I will still have the same diff with pointers. Or there is something that I don't understand

Comment: you could check out the remote branch and put the file aside (i.e. copy it to a different folder) than compare with yours. when you checkout a branch it "populates" the lfs files with pointers with the file content.

Comment: I will try that. But I have a lot of json files concerned by this 'problem', it will take a lot of time to do this for each file.

Comment: you can set .json files not to be in lfs

Comment: How can i do that? Is it okay to have some files in lfs and others not?

Comment: anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving a Git conflict with binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278081/resolving-a-git-conflict-with-binary-files)